# Material for lid of a solar cooker

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation

Normal glass allows visible light to pass through, but it blocks ultraviolet rays. If I use a glass which allows both the kinds of rays to pass through it as the lid of my solar cooker as lid, will that increase the heat inside?

Comment: This does not appear to be a question.

Answer (score 1):

> normal glass allows visible light to pass through it and block
>   ultraviolet rays so, if i use a glass which allow both the rays to
>   pass through it ,in my solar cooker as lid so that will increase heat
>   inside my soalr box

Yes.

However, as the vast majority of UV is blocked by the ozone layer, the effect will be tiny.